# Does integrated authentication in IIS pass the username and password in plain text when outside an Intranet?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

We have a SharePoint 2007 server which is completely stand alone from the rest of the network. It is it's own Domain Controller for it's own Forest (Windows Server 2008). It is available to the Internet. The IIS security setting is Integrated Authentication but when a user is prompted for their credentials when trying to access from outside the Domain, will their username and password be passed in basic text or encrypted somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrated will only use Kerberos V5 or NTLM. Both are protected means of authentication, though I'd hesitate to call it encrypted; nothing else in the exchange will be secured. Use SSL to ensure encryption.

Comment: Thanks, SSL is being planned but was interest in the meantime.

Comment: With Windows Auth it's not only encrypted, it's hashed, so it can't be reversed.  However, if the right person got a hold of a hash key, they can do damage with it too (far less likely, but possible), so the recommendation to use SSL is best.